# How to show Wordpress page number and total number of pages (i.e., page 1 of 3)

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to display the page numbers in index.php, search.php and archive.php

As far as I'm aware, the variable $page contains the current page number, this works, but I just need the number of pages.

Also is there an easy way to get the URL for the next page and previous page for use any way you wish? next_posts_link(); and previous_posts_link(); don't seem to be able to do what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (or look at the source of) this plugin:

[WordPress > WP Page Numbers](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-page-numbers/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there should be something similar to the $page variable. But if it's not in the WP codex, you could dive into the wonderful world of [Custom Queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query) .

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the variable `$page` contains the current page number, this works, but I just need the number of pages.

I know that you have to count the record in global `$paged`